# Scheduler based on non-final variable value in Android

Tags: android

I am looking for a code snippet for Android which will allow me to invoke my thread for execution only on specific variable value.

For Ex: If the variable say X reaches from 0 to 50 then invoke the thread execution and will reset the variable X to 0 again. And this process will go on until and unless I stopped the thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private boolean stopthread=false;
handler = new Handler();
private int x=0;

if(!stopthread){
  if(x>0 && x<50){
  x=0;
 final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
public void run() {
    tv.append("Hello");

 }
};
}else{
  x=x+1;
 }
  }
```